# What is the correct tag to use if I want to get an answer in any programming language?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I started a bounty of 
[[How to implement a dealer class without storing a deck of cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619574/how-to-implement-a-dealer-class-without-storing-a-deck-of-cards)]

I originally put a tag of c# with it. However, I think maybe there are people can solve this question but is used to focus on other programming languages. So I'd like to get answers in any programming language, and do the work to convert it in target language myself.

Now I retag it with [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic). But I see it no more appears in any specific language.

What is the correct tag I should use to do this?

---

**revision:**
I finally think that tagged with both target language and language-agnostic would be more helpful in my case.

Comment: [language-agnostic] really. That's the one.

Comment: @Bart: Hi Bart, thank you. But it even not shown in any specific language, I think if someone select a tag of some language will not see.

Comment: If you want an answer in any programming language, then why do you want it to show only in specific languages? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: I want it seen by people who choose any specific language; thus I have higher probability to get a solution from someone who write in some language.

Comment: Even if you could read/translate from other languages...likely you'd do it differently in python or C++ or Algol or FORTRAN. If you want a C# answer, use C#. Believe me, there are *plenty* of knowledgeable C# answerers. No need to skip the tag or worse spam C/C++/others.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks. The problem is, the ***knowledgeable C# answerers*** you told, is not necessarily to give me an answer, answering the questions is by one's willing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic), you can't possibly tag it with all languages and there isn't a tag that has a feature attached to it which would add it to all languages. You just have to trust that those people interested in programming in general, would be subscribed to the agnostic tag.

Comment: That's too bad. Will it be better if I choose the most three language I preffered?

Comment: @KenKin: No, choose the language you're likely to implement it on. If there isn't such a language, [tag:language-agnostic] is the one.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: Thank you. But it must be in "one of" programming languages, so that I can read and rewrite the algorithms in my targeting language, currently c#.

Comment: @KenKin: Then it's not language-agnostic, is it?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I don't know if "one of any existing programming language" meet the definition of "language-agnostic". Even if I got an answer of `Ada`/`prolog`/`B language` are just fine.